# Is it possible to access a class attribute in a python decorator?

Tags: python, class, attributes, decorator, class-attributes

Is it possible to access a class attribute in a python decorator?

Code:

```
class ButtonView(discord.ui.View):
  def __init__(self, allPages, author, *, timeout = 180):
    super().__init__(timeout=timeout)
    self.allPages = allPages

  @discord.ui.button(label=self.allPages, style=discord.ButtonStyle.secondary, custom_id="current_page_button")
  async def current_page_button_callback(self, button, interaction):
    ...
```

I get a warning on `self.allPages` in `@discord.ui.button()`:

> self.allPages is not defined

Comment: The decorator is applied *to the function, when the class is being created*, so there is no `self` from which the attributes could be accessed.

Comment: Okay, thanks! I managed to overcome this by using the discord.ui.Button and made a few changes. The code is now a little bit more complicated and not as elegant looking, but it does the job!